# vtkXMLPolyData Writer/Reader not reversible

Tags: python, serialization, xml-serialization, vtk

I have a `vtkPolyData` object `c` and I'm trying to serialize it through XML using `vtkXMLPolyDataWriter`:

```
import vtk

print(c.GetNumberOfCells(), c.GetNumberOfPoints())

writer = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetInputData(c)
writer.WriteToOutputStringOn()
writer.Update()
s = writer.GetOutputString()

reader = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataReader()
reader.SetInputString(s)
reader.Update()
c2 = reader.GetOutput()

print(c2.GetNumberOfCells(), c2.GetNumberOfPoints())
```

which prints:

```
8 6
0 0
```

Is there a way to make this process fully reversible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I forgot this line in the reading process:

```
reader.ReadFromInputStringOn()
```

I also changed `vtkXMLPolyDataReader` to `vtkPolyDataReader` (same with Writer).